# /home/ec2-user/grails-2.4.3 is not a directory on the Jenkins master (but perhaps it exists on some slaves)

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to setup jenkins on ec2 instance managed by elastic beanstalk , i have previously setup the jenkins on simple ec2 with no elastic beanstalk involved, and there was no problem.

So the issue is when i configure the jenkins in manage jenkins -> configure system , i tried to setup the path of grails and jdk but for both case , when i provide the     Install directory for grails or jdk i get this error,

```
 /home/ec2-user/grails-2.4.3 is not a directory on the Jenkins master (but perhaps it exists on some slaves)
```

and in case of jdk i get this

```
/usr/bin/java is not a directory on the Jenkins master (but perhaps it exists on some slaves)
```

Also, when i provide the path to only

```
/home/ec2-user
```

it does not show this error, but if append any path after this it started showing this error .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YpRg.png)

i didn't understand why is this showing up ,i simply setup the jenkins on ec2 (managed by elastic beanstalk) as i done previously on normal ec2, i think it may be due to elastic beanstalk involvement, please help me out

Comment: how exactly are you setting this up? via SSH?

Comment: can u please explain what u r asking ?

Comment: how did you install jenkins on elastic beanstalk? did you use a custom AMI? a Docker? or simply SSHed into the beanstalk instance and tried to setup jenkins there?

Comment: yeah i setup it via ssh, simply ssh to elastic beanstalk and setup there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure elastic beanstalk (EB) is the right choice for Jenkins. EB will take your installed server down and replace it with a fresh install as it see fit. It's most suitable for stateless web applications rather than a continuous integration server such as jenkins. so first advice - stick with ec2 for jenkins.

As for your error, elastic beanstalk will run its own server version, different from the one you've used on ec2, so java and grails may not even be installed on that server.

If you do want to set this up on elastic beanstalk you'll have to install java and grails via ab `ebextension` file (see [tiring documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages)).

Comment: your suggestion works for me, i have setup the jenkins on ec2 only, just one issue one i am having is while uploading file to s3, can you please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156963/the-bucket-you-are-attempting-to-access-must-be-addressed-using-the-specified-en