# The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint , while uploading from jenkins to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i am trying to deploy the war file from jenkins to elastic bean stalk, the build is successful , but when it tries to upload to s3 , it is showing this error

```
Uploading file awseb-2152283815930847266.zip as s3://elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-779583297123/jenkins/My App-jenkins-Continuous-Delivery-
MyApp-Stage-promotion-Deploy-14.zip
Cleaning up temporary file /tmp/awseb-2152283815930847266.zip
FATAL: Deployment Failure
java.io.IOException: Deployment Failure
```

further error shows

```
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. 
(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code:
```

Jenkins configuration for elastic beanstalk

```
My beanstalk is in "ap-southeast-2" region  
Bucket name is "elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-779583297123"
```

You can have a look at this for more clarity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMw61.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like *Beanstalk* and the *S3* bucket are in different regions. You stated that *Beanstalk* is in `ap-southeast-2`, while it seems that the *S3* bucket is in `ap-southeast-1`. Create that bucket in `ap-southeast-2`.

Comment: so i have just find a workaround for it and i just simply not provided the bucket name in the configuration , so it automatically manages it self, but now something strange that is happening is , can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173569/jenkins-aws-elastic-deployment-plugin-just-create-a-new-ec2-on-each-update