# The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip 5.0.0.beta2 in my latest rails (4.2.6) project. The application is hosted on Heroku. I can upload an image and it seems to be stored in a bucket on Amazon S3. However in the browser the image appears to have a broken url, although it's point to the bucket on Amazon S3, the url is:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/gigbnb/profiles/profile_pics/000/000/002/small/anthony_candaele-300x300.jpg?1464956858

When I enter this url in the browser, I get an xml page with this error message:

```
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the     specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

It looks like there is an issue with the S3 endpoint.

However I set the region (eu-west-1) in configuration file:

```
config/environments/production.rb


config.paperclip_defaults = {
   storage: :s3,
   s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
   s3_credentials: {
     bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
     access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
     secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
   }
}
```

My Github repository is at:

https://github.com/acandael/gigbnb

Does anyone have an idea what's going on?

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: see if answer on this link is of help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156963/the-bucket-you-are-attempting-to-access-must-be-addressed-using-the-specified-en - Thanks!!

Comment: here is a workaround that fixed the issue for me: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a [workaround](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2151) that fixed the issue for me. It's presented by aminariana

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this is that your s3 client is created using a region other than the one your bucket is sitting on.